# All-Different-Except Constraint in Z3

Tags: big-o, z3, z3py, bitvector

Is there a way to generate an all-different-except constraint in Z3 with only O(n) statements? I know that [XCSP3](https://xcsp.org/format3.pdf) offers this.

This currently can be done like so with O(n^2) statements:

```
for i in range(len(G) - 1):
    s.add( [ Or(G[i] == 0, G[i] != G[j]) for j in range(i + 1, len(G)) ] )
```

If it matters I'm interested in comparing bit vectors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Z3 does come with a `Distinct` predicate that ensures all elements are different, but to the best of my knowledge there is no built-in `distinct-except`.

To encode this sort of a constraint, I'd use an array to keep track of the cardinality of inserted elements. Something like this:

```py
from z3 import *

def distinct_except(G, ignored):
   if len(G) < 2:
       return BoolSort().cast(True)

   A = K(G[0].sort(), 0);
   for i in range(len(G)):
       A = Store(A, G[i], If(G[i] == ignored, 0, 1 + Select(A, G[i])))

   res = True
   for i in range(len(G)):
       res = And(res, Select(A, G[i]) <= 1)

   return res
```

We simply insert the elements into an array, incrementing the count by 1 if the element is not ignored, otherwise putting in a 0. This avoids costly if-then-else nodes as the array is linearly built. We then walk over the list again and make sure we never stored anything larger than 1.

This will keep the sizes of the expressions `res` and `A` linear, and z3 should be able to deal with it fairly efficiently. I'd like to hear if you find otherwise.

Here're a few tests to see it in action:

```py
# Test: Create four variables, assert they are distinct in the above sense
a, b, c, d = BitVecs('a b c d', 32)
s = Solver()
s.add(distinct_except([a, b, c, d], 0))

# Clearly sat:
print s.check()
print s.model()

# Add a constraint that a and b are equal
# Still SAT, because we can make a and b 0
s.add(a == b)
print s.check()
print s.model()

# Force a to be non-zero
s.add(a != 0)

# Now we have unsat:
print s.check()
```

This prints:

```
sat
[b = 1024, a = 16, c = 1, d = 536870912]
sat
[c = 33554432, a = 0, d = 32768, b = 0]
unsat
```

Note that you can always use `print s.sexpr()` to see the expressions you build before you call `s.check()` to see how they grow as your input lists get larger.

Comment: I'm impressed, thank you. I haven't worked with theory of arrays before. Why isn't the 9th line like such: `A = Store(A, G[i], If(G[i] == ignored, 0 + Select(A, G[i]), 1 + Select(A, G[i])))`?

Comment: If the value is ignored it'll always be 0. (You start with an array of 0's.) So, what you'd write would work too, but it absolutely does nothing as if `G[i]` is ignored then `Select(A, G[i])` is going to be always 0. So, keeping it just `0` is perfectly good. Try writing out a few examples yourself and run through what it would look like.